# Keras SimpleRNNCell appears to fail to distribute learning among all its weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

This question is about SimpleRNNCell, a class in Tensorflow to perform basic Recurrent Neural Network. Unless there's something fundamentally wrong in my code, it appears that training is not spread over all the available weights but only a subset of them, making irrelevant the recurrent machinery.
I've written with keras a minimal program with just one RNN cell and a dense layer. When I print out the learned weights the state weight doesn't appear to have changed since its initialization. Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import RNN
from tensorflow.keras.layers import SimpleRNN, SimpleRNNCell
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from tensorflow import random as rnd

#Fix the seed
rnd.set_seed(0)


#The dataset can be downloaded from https://mantas.info/wp/wp-content/uploads/simple_esn/MackeyGlass_t17.txt
data = np.loadtxt('MackeyGlass_t17.txt')

#Normalize
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaled = scaler.fit_transform(data.reshape(-1, 1))

#Split Dataset in Train and Test
train, test = scaled[0:-100], scaled[-100:]

#Split into input and output 
train_X, train_y = train[:-1], train[1:]
test_X, test_y = test[:-1], test[1:] 

#Reshaping 
train_X = train_X.reshape((train_X.shape[0], 1, train_X.shape[1]))
test_X = test_X.reshape((test_X.shape[0], 1, test_X.shape[1]))

#Batch and epochs
batch_size = 20
epochs = 2

#Design and run the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(RNN(SimpleRNNCell(1)))
#model.add(SimpleRNN(1))) # This generates the same results as the above line
model.add(Dense(train_y.shape[1]))
model.compile(loss='huber', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data=(test_X, test_y), verbose=0, shuffle=False)

#Print the weights of the dense layer
for layer in model.layers: print(layer.get_weights())
```

If I run this code with 2 epochs I receive the following output:

> [array([[-0.8942287]], dtype=float32), **array([[1.]]**, dtype=float32), array([0.05435111], dtype=float32)]
> [array([[-1.272426]], dtype=float32), array([0.04711587], dtype=float32)]

If I run this code with 3 epochs I receive the following output:

> [array([[-0.89395165]], dtype=float32), **array([[1.]]**, dtype=float32), array([0.06734365], dtype=float32)]
> [array([[-1.2927996]], dtype=float32), array([0.05247825], dtype=float32)]

Note that with a scalar series and just one cell, matrices and vectors reduce to only one element, so I end up having 5 weights: respectively the input weight, the state weight, the input bias, the dense layer weight, the dense layer bias. All these weights changed during learning apart from the state weight, which is stuck to its initialization i.e. 1.0.
Why the learning process doesn't affect the state weight? Is there any obvious mistake in the way I implemented the model?

Note:
**Ubuntu 20.04, Python 3.9.15, Tensorflow 2.7.0, no GPU**.

After accepting the answer I modified my code. Lines:

```
#Split into input and output 
train_X, train_y = train[:-1], train[1:]
test_X, test_y = test[:-1], test[1:] 

#Reshaping 
train_X = train_X.reshape((train_X.shape[0], 1, train_X.shape[1]))
test_X = test_X.reshape((test_X.shape[0], 1, test_X.shape[1]))
```

should be replaced by:

```
def get_XY(dat, time_steps):
    # Indices of target array
    Y_ind = np.arange(time_steps, len(dat), time_steps)
    Y = dat[Y_ind]
    # Prepare X
    rows_x = len(Y)
    X = dat[range(time_steps*rows_x)]
    X = np.reshape(X, (rows_x, time_steps, 1))    
    return X, Y
 
time_steps = 12
train_X, train_y = get_XY(train, time_steps)
test_X, test_y = get_XY(train, time_steps)
```

to get the state weight to be trained.
Now the output with 3 epochs is:

> [array([[-0.63304466]], dtype=float32), array([[0.9038045]], dtype=float32), array([0.06537308], dtype=float32)]
> [array([[-0.97942555]], dtype=float32), array([-0.07855547], dtype=float32)]

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled that you are importing `keras` as is and not as part of tensorflow. Could you try placing `import tensorflow as tf` at the top and replacing each `from keras.xxx import xxx` with `from tf.keras.xxx import xxx`?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your entry. I have replaced my import section in the way you advise (so for instance instead of from _keras.layers import Dense_ now it is from _tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense_, see also the updated code in my original question) but nothing changed: the state weight is still stuck to its initial setting

Comment: I've also done some debugging in the library: it **appears** to me that the state passed to the state matrix is always zeroed. If so that means that SimpleRNN just isn't using its recurrent machinery but I' m struggling to believe that is a possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for taking the time to providing complete working code to reproduce the issue.

The problem here isn't the RNN, it's the shape of your input data:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1pkFuU_nMyJnVHF3TvCSQ49e-IORFu3PQ?authuser=1#scrollTo=lIYdn1woOS1n

Keras, expects RNN inputs to have shape `(batch, time, features)`, your data with shape `(10k, 1, 1)`

It only ever sees one time step, so it never has a chance to learn how to handle the previous time-step.

Try this tool for a fix: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/timeseries_dataset_from_array

Comment: Hi Thank you so much for considering my question. I'm still not completely clear with this issue and was wondering if you could kindly elaborate a little more. When you say that "Keras expects inputs to have shape (batch, time, features)" I do find correspondence in tensorflow documentation when SImpleRNN is called. However I'm using fit() and in the fit() documentation things appears a little less clear to me as the input is None by default and can be a number of things. Are you saying here that fit() eventually calls some __call__() function implemented is SimpleRNN or its parents/ancestors?

Comment: After a bit of browsing I'm seeing that the practice of using 1 time step shouldn't prevent a LSTM from exploiting its recurrent machinery (see here for instance: https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras) but perhaps the SimpleRNN recurrent machinery works differently from the LSTM one? - Thank you again for any insight.

Comment: After some more researching I've seen that SimpleRNN have to be treated differently from LSTM. I found particularly useful this explanation:
https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras
from where I took the code to fix my toy program.